# Approximate value for a double integral using monte carlo method in R

Tags: r, statistics, integration

I'm trying to implement the monte carlo method in R to find the approximate value for the following double integral:

[image]

I have the following code:

```
mean.estimated <- function(nvals) {
    X <- runif(nvals)
    Y <- runif(nvals)
    sum(exp((2*X + 3*Y)^5))/ nvals
}


monte.carlo <- function(nreps,nvals) {
    estimates <- NULL
    for (i in 1:nreps){
        estimates[i] <- mean.estimated(nvals)
    }
    estimates
}

simvalues <- monte.carlo(200,2000)
```

But it only produces Inf values. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

With `X` and `Y` bounded between 0 and 1, we have that `2*X + 3*Y` takes a value between 0 and 5.

When it is the case that `2*X + 3*Y` exceeds about 3.72, we have that `exp((2*X + 3*Y)^5)` is infinite:

```
> exp((3.72)^5)
[1] Inf
```

If any one value in the sum is infinite, the sum is infinite.  I am not going to compute the odds here, but it is somewhat unlikely that of 2000 samples, every one will have `2*X + 3*Y` not exceeding ~3.72.  So unlikely that you get `Inf` for every sample.

Comment: @ Matthew Lundberg So, is this problem impossible to solve via the Monte Carlo method?

Comment: As stated, it is impossible to compute numerically, as a large part of the domain will cause `exp` to return infinity.

Comment: I tried even with a small number of trials and repetitions, 2 and 1 respectively, and the generated numbers are way too large. I'm sorry for insisting on the matter but this was given to me as an assignment. Should i turn in the assignment as impossible to solve @Matthew Lundberg?

Comment: The Wolfram site returns this as the indefinite integral of e^x^5: `integral  integral e^(x^5)  dx dx = c_1 x+c_2+((-x^5)^(4/5) Gamma(1/5, -x^5))/(5 x^3)+(x^2 Gamma(2/5, -x^5))/(5 (-x^5)^(2/5))`